# Reverse do_shortcode() effect

Tags: wordpress

i have created some basic shortcodes [row],[cols] and [img]. I can use them like:

```
[row cols="2" ]

     [col cols="2"]In faucibus[/col]

     [col cols="2"][img src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/08/32-300x300.jpeg"] [/col]

[/row]
```

What this makes is simple, create the following bootstrap structure:

```
 <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">In faucibus</div>

     <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><img src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/08/32-300x300.jpeg\&quot;" alt="\&quot;\&quot;"></div>

 </div>
```

I have made this with do_shortcode($content) because in one shortcode can be another shortcode.

The question:

Is possible to take the html result and converted back to shortcode format based on the shortcodes functions i have already defined?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having the same problem to a simple front-end editor I'm building. I find Visual Composer very large for simple projects.

A possible solution is to use jQuery to read the attributes and contents of, say a div, and generate the resulting shortcode. So, in your case take the values of 'class' and convert to shortcode equivalent.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is the solution i used back in 2015, when working on a "Visual Composer" like project.i used some attributes in my divs then send on save the modifications through ajax and generate the shortcode again. only now i saw your answer. Thank you ;)